# Is there a way to check Javascript function returning object / array is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What I am trying to achieve here is that, I made a simple utility function and that should return 'true' or 'false', based on the given argument to the isEmpty method.

// The below log should return 'false', But it's returning 'true'

```
console.log(isEmpty( () => {key: 1} ));
```

What I tried so far

```
 function isEmpty(value) {
  const type = typeof value;
    if ((value !== null && type === 'object') || type === 'function') {
       const properties = Object.keys(value);
        return properties.length === 0 || properties.size === 0
      } 
      return !value;
   }
```

And it's working for below cases

```
        console.log(isEmpty( {} )) // true
        console.log(isEmpty( [] )) // true
        console.log(isEmpty( Object.create(null) )) // true
        console.log(isEmpty( null )) // true
        console.log(isEmpty( '' )) // true

        console.log(isEmpty( {key: 1} )) // false
        console.log(isEmpty( [1,2,3] )) // false
```

But it's not working, when we get the return object / array from the function

```
    console.log(isEmpty( () => ({key: 1}) )) 
    console.log(isEmpty( () => ([1,2,3]) ))
```

Comment: If it is function you could execute the function and call `isEmpty` on the value returned. Something like `if(type === 'function') return isEmpty(value())` ?

Comment: is `() => {key: 1}` supposed to be `() => ({key: 1})` ?

Comment: `console.log(isEmpty( () => {key: 1} )) ` in this case you are passing a function not the return value. If you still want to check if the return value from function you have to invoke the function and check the same

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks, Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.keys()` on a function will always result in an empty array (no matter the return type). This is due to the fact that the keys of a function are not enumerable (the keys being `name` and `length`), and `Object.keys()` will only give back the keys which can be enumerated. This means the length of the array of keys will always be `0`, meaning your function will give back `true` even though the function it is passed returns a non-empty value.

If you can invoke the `value` (if it is a function), it will allow you to get the returned value out of it (ie: an object or array), and then recurse with your function that you currently have:

```js
function isEmpty(value) {
  const type = typeof value;
  if (value !== null && type === 'object') {
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(value) || {};
    const properties = Object.keys(value) + Object.keys(prototype);
    return properties.length === 0 || properties.size === 0
  } else if(type === 'function') {
    const res = value();
    return isEmpty(res);
  }
  return !value;
}

console.log(isEmpty( {} )) // true
console.log(isEmpty( [] )) // true
console.log(isEmpty( Object.create(null) )) // true
console.log(isEmpty( null )) // true
console.log(isEmpty( '' )) // true

console.log(isEmpty(() => ({}))); // true
console.log(isEmpty(() => () => () => ({}))); // true

console.log(isEmpty( {key: 1} )) // false
console.log(isEmpty( [1,2,3] )) // false

console.log(isEmpty(() => ({key: 1}))); // false
console.log(isEmpty( () => ([1,2,3]) )) // false


console.log(isEmpty(() => (Object.create({key: 1})))) // false
```

Comment: And it's not working for this scenario  -  


console.log(isEmpty( () => (Object.create({key: 1}) )));

Comment: @RajuPedda see edit, (you need to account for the enumerable properties on the prototype as well)

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you will have to check the type of the `value` and if it is a `function` then invoke to get the result.

If the function passed have side effects they would be called, which could cause some issues.

```
function isEmpty(value) {
    const type = typeof value;

    // If passed a function, invoke it and get the result
    if (type === 'function') {
        value = value();
    }

    if (value && (type === 'object' || type === 'function')) {
        const properties = Object.keys(value);
        return properties.length === 0 || properties.size === 0
    } 

    return !value;
}
```

When you call a function like `() => { key: 1 }` you are actually creating a function which looks like

```
function {
    key: 1
}
```

which means that the function do not have a return value. Instead you should use it like this `() => ({ key: 1 })` which will create a 
function like:

```
function {
    return { key: 1 }
}
```

https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAYgVzMAjDAvDAFASgwPhgG8YBrAUwE8AuGNAXwChRJZFkAmDbPdQrEhRp0Y9HEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.3&externalPlugins=

Comment: It's throwing error, when I send null value 
 console.log(isEmpty( () => (null )));

Comment: Sorry, had `!value` instead of `value`.. It should work now :)

Comment: And it's not working for this scenario -      console.log(isEmpty( () => (Object.create({key: 1}) )));